# Carve Hole in A metal water bottle model

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I am making a 3D model out of my stainless steel water bottle but I can't get right the carved part on the bottom of the bottle

[image: Hole in Stainless steel water bottle]

I tried using the boolean modifier coupled with a bevel and a subdivision modifier but still not what I wanted 
[image: Attempted result]

I used a Triangle made from a plane and a solidify modifier and bevel the sharp top edge to make the boolean. Here are what it looks on my blender file

[image: blender Viewport]

And here is the reference image for the bottom part of the water bottle taken by me

[image: Bottom View of the water Bottle]

Also since I can't make the edge correct for the bottom part I was worried on how to make the Curved Hole on the bottle Cap (I haven't started the bottle cap so I'm just asking for advice on how to do it)

Here is the reference image for the top and front of the bottle cap

[image: Top View of the Bottle Cap]

[image: Front View of the bottle cap]

I have no idea on how to make this correctly and I would like some help. Thanks for the future advice and help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the bottom of your bottle you can model it, use a *Mirror* modifier as it is symmetrical, give it enough topology as it will need to be bent, duplicate with an *Array*, then at last use a *Simple Deform* / *Bend* mode to make it turn around 360°. Apply the *Array* and *Simple Deform* and remove the doubles.

[image]

For the bottle cap it seems a bit more complicated as the cut shape doesn't deform to the center. So what you could do is create a cylinder, only keep a segment, bevel it:

[image]

Cut a hole, for example with a *Boolean* modifier or just some vertices displacements. Extrude downwards, fill the faces.

[image]

Create an empty at the center of the cylinder object. Give the cylinder an *Array* modifier > *Object Offset*, with the empty as *Object*. Rotate the empty so that it recreates a cylinder.

[image]

Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, bring some corrections to the topology in order to sharp the edges etc.

[image]

Comment: *"The topology game is strong with this one..."*

Comment: Hello, for the bottom part of the bottle have you used a subdivision surface?  Because I tried to model it by myself but I could not get the form right, and also did you extrude the bottom end of your plane? Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Hello, yes at one point I gave it a Subdivision Surface, and added some edge loops, moved some vertices to make the modifier work correctly and to have sharp angles. I'm not sure what you mean by "did you extrude the bottom end", do you mean how to close the bottom? Yes make a last extrude. At the end keep a copy of your object with the modifiers unapplied to make sure you have a non-destructive version somewhere, apply the modifiers, remove doubles, etc...

Comment: Yes, I figure that out by myself, thank you, it was a lot of work for me to model the bottom part but I end up with something acceptable, I'm now continuing for the cap. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I run in another problem, How should I add the bottom of the water bottle and the bottle cap? I managed to make the cap and the bottom part but when trying to merge the bottle cap with a cylinder using a Union Boolean it merged with a clear seams. How should i merge the loops ?

Comment: do you mean you want to merge bottom and cap into one unique mesh? The cap is another object than the bottle, so you don't have any reason to merge it with the bottom mesh, if this what you mean. Also, try to avoid boolean if you can, I doubt you need it after making the cap. Maybe edit your question if you want to show some additional images of your current object, to make your problems more understandable...

Comment: Hello I can't edit my comment for 5 mn so I copy and paste it you can find a link to see the screen of my viewport:  How should I add the bottom of the water bottle and the bottle cap? I managed to make the cap and the bottom part but when trying to merge the bottle cap with a cylinder using a Union Boolean it merged with clear seams. How should I merge the loops? The link for the screenshot of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/vJwlqRE (I applied a material to enlighten the issue). Link to see the original Mesh for the Bottle Cap Before applying the array modifier: https://imgur.com/a/eXqrojn

Comment: why do you need a boolean? you just need to extrude down the bottom edge. Maybe the current problem is some flipped normals, or double vertices, or inner faces? Hard to say but check all these...

Comment: So basically I just need to extrude for the bottle cap ? But for the bottom of the Bottle should I extrude and bridge the edge loops ? Or just let it be like that unmerged ? Thanks !

Comment: first thing: you don't need to join the 2 meshes (cap and bottom) because in real life these are 2 different objects, so it's a good reason not to do it if that's what you're planning to do. Second thing, to make a longer cap, extrude its bottom edge down, and to make a longer bottle, extrude its top edge up. If you really want to join top and bottom, use bridge edge loops, if it creates bad topology, try to rearrange it, depending on the problem...

Comment: Oh okay, thanks you very much you saved me !

Comment: maybe follow some tutorials on modeling coca cola bottle, etc, it could help

Comment: Okay I'll check it thanks you very much appreciated.